# Using C math.h to calculate the sin of a number

Tags: c, math.h

I'm an absolute beginner to C and I've read a few books but never really played with it.  I'm starting to try to apply what I've read with a very simple program that returns the sin of a number.  The hardest thing I've encountered with C is knowing how and when to use pointers.

I'm sure this is simple but here is how I've written my test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
   double x;

   printf("Enter a number to calculate the sin(x): \n");
   scanf("%lf", &x);

   printf("sin(%lf) = %lf\n", x, sin(x));

   return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling and executing this code in Ubuntu

```
gcc -lm sinCalc.c && ./a.out
```

Error I'm receiving is this:

```
/tmp/blaha.o: In function `main':
sinCalc.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `sin'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: This program looks like it ought to work, except maybe for the usual sorts of problems with `scanf`, which should never be used, but you can get away with it in a very simple program like this.  What is the problem?

Comment: What's the question regarding `sin()`? You should probably ask the other one in a different post, as it's completely unrelated.

Comment: You should better put the `-lm` after the source file in the compilation command. Many linkers will take only the symbols they know are needed from a library, and when `-lm` is before `sinCalc.c`, the linker does not yet know that it will need `sin`.

Comment: Keep in mind `sin()` takes radians not degrees. You also need to put the `-lm` after the source file.

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: @Zack why is using scanf bad?

Comment: Because it is easy to use wrongly, and it is hard to recover from errors, in general.  In this case, you won't go too far wrong, though you should use `if (scanf("%lf", &x) == 1) printf(...)` so that if your input fails (you type 'pi' instead of 3.14159), you don't try using the variable x with an indeterminate value.  In more complex cases, it is hard to handle failures part way through a list of 6 conversion specifications, especially if there are literal characters in the format.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That makes perfect sense.  Thanks for the thorough explanation

Comment: .@JonathanLeffler In addition to what you mentioned, some format specifiers are just as dangerous as `gets`, and numeric overflow in a conversion is technically runtime-undefined behavior ("technically" because I doubt any real C library would do anything worse than produce garbage in the output variable).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Undefined symbols are resolved left to right, so

```
gcc sinCalc.c -lm && ./a.out
```

should work.

> Are they [structs] like an interface in Java?

No. Structs are an aggregate of a number (1 or more) of types that can be dealt with as a single unit in certain circumstances (assignment, parameter passing).

Comment: Note that Jens answered the original version of the question which contained two unrelated questions, the second being whether a C `struct` was similar to a Java `interface`.